# Modifying the size of an image in an <iframe>

Tags: html

I have a image with a resolution:

```
<iframe src="....?resolution=640x480" width="800" height="452" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

I change the width of the image, and the image doesn't change. If I specify a width of less than 640 in `width="800"`, the image's size reduces, but more than 640 the image remains unchanged. Why?

Comment: Do you need the resolution to be 640x480? And what are the dimensions (width & height of your image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an `<iframe>`, not an image, and its contents won’t scale beyond the actual resolution of the image (as you can see in the URL, that’s 640 pixels wide).

If you want an actual image, use `<img>`.